# ethereumjs-abi equivalent for Golang?

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, golang, encoding

[ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) is great for easily ABI encoding and decoding in javascript. Is there an equivalently simple package for Golang?

Geth's `accounts/abi`package does this, but there's a lot of setup and it's hard to change the types, because you have to specify a full ABI-JSON. I imagine this is a common need and solved. Any suggestions?

Example of ethereumjs-abi:

`let encoded = abi.rawEncode(["bytes32", "bytes"], [val1, val2])`

Answer (score 2):

Using Ethereum's official `golang`s ABI is easy too:

This is how you extract encoded values from transaction's input:

```
m,exists:=erc20_token_abi.Methods[method_name]
if exists {
    method_input,err:=m.Inputs.UnpackValues(input_data_bytes)
}
```

This is how you encode values for transaction's input :

```
encoded_input,err:=contract_abi.Pack(method_name,method_params...)
```

This is how you decode the `output` returned by the EVM once the contract Call is finished:

```
 ret,gas,_,failed,err:=core.ApplyMessage(evm_obj,msg,gp)
 output_int:=big.NewInt(0)
 if !((err!=nil) || (failed)) {
     err=erc20_token_abi.Unpack(&output_int,"totalSupply",ret)
     if err!=nil {
         log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Contract %v: can;t upack total supply: %v",hex.EncodeToString(addr.Bytes()),err))
     } else {
         log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("totalSupply=%v",output_int.String()))
     }
 }
```

To create ABI object:

```
erc20_methods_abi, err = abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(erc20_methods_abi_json_str)) (erc20_methods_abi_json_st
```

For example, this is the code in `golang` I am using to encode a generic input (received as string with comma separated values, and an ABI in a string) from a C++ app:

```
//export EncodeInput4ContractCall
func EncodeInput4ContractCall(out_encoded_input unsafe.Pointer,output_len_ptr *C.int,in_output_max_len C.int,in_contract_abi *C.char,in_method_name *C.char,in_method_params *C.char) C.int {

    contract_abi_str:=C.GoString(in_contract_abi)
    method_name:=C.GoString(in_method_name)
    method_params_str:=C.GoString(in_method_params)

    contract_abi,err:=abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(contract_abi_str))
    if err!=nil {
        write_back_error(out_encoded_input,output_len_ptr,err)
        return 1;
    }
    method,exists:=contract_abi.Methods[method_name]
    if !exists {
        err:=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Method '%v' not found in the ABI",method_name))
        write_back_error(out_encoded_input,output_len_ptr,err)
        return 1
    }
    params:=strings.Split(method_params_str,",")
    if len(params)!=len(method.Inputs) {
        err:=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid number of parameters. Method requires %v, but %v provided",len(method.Inputs),len(params)))
        write_back_error(out_encoded_input,output_len_ptr,err)
        return 1
    }
    method_params:=make([]interface{},0,8)
    for i,input:=range method.Inputs {
        v,err:=param_decode(params[i],&input)
        if err!=nil {
            err:=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to decode parameter %v (%v): %v",(i+1),input.Name,err))
            write_back_error(out_encoded_input,output_len_ptr,err)
            return 1
        }
        method_params=append(method_params,v)
    }

    encoded_input,err:=contract_abi.Pack(method_name,method_params...)
    if err!=nil {
        write_back_error(out_encoded_input,output_len_ptr,err)
        return 1;
    }
    encoded_input_hex:=hex.EncodeToString(encoded_input)

    output_bytes:=[]byte(encoded_input_hex);
    length:=_Ctype_ulong(len(output_bytes))
    if (length>_Ctype_ulong(in_output_max_len)) {
        err:=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Output buffer too small for generated output (%v>%v)",length,in_output_max_len))
        write_back_error(out_encoded_input,output_len_ptr,err)
        return 1
    }

    *output_len_ptr=C.int(length)

    var c_bytes unsafe.Pointer
    c_bytes=C.CBytes(output_bytes)
    C.memcpy(out_encoded_input,c_bytes,length)
    C.free(c_bytes)

    return 0;
}

func param_decode(param string,arg *abi.Argument) (v interface{},err error) {
    param=strings.TrimSpace(param)
    switch(arg.Type.T) {
        case abi.StringTy:
            str_val:=new(string)
            v=str_val
            err=json.Unmarshal([]byte(param),v)
        case abi.UintTy,abi.IntTy:
            val:=big.NewInt(0)
            _,success:=val.SetString(param,10)
            if !success {
                err=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid numeric (base 10) value: %v",param))
            }
            v=val
        case abi.AddressTy:
            if !((len(param)==(common.AddressLength*2+2)) || (len(param)==common.AddressLength*2)) {
                err=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid address length (%v), must be 40 (unprefixed) or 42 (prefixed) chars",len(param)))
            } else {
                var addr common.Address
                if len(param)==(common.AddressLength*2+2) {
                    addr=common.HexToAddress(param)
                } else {
                    var data []byte
                    data,err=hex.DecodeString(param)
                    addr.SetBytes(data)
                }
                v=addr
            }
        case abi.HashTy:
            if !((len(param)==(common.HashLength*2+2)) || (len(param)==common.HashLength*2)) {
                err=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid hash length, must be 64 (unprefixed) or 66 (prefixed) chars"))
            } else {
                var hash common.Hash
                if len(param)==(common.HashLength*2+2) {
                    hash=common.HexToHash(param)
                } else {
                    var data []byte
                    data,err=hex.DecodeString(param)
                    hash.SetBytes(data)
                }
                v=hash
            }
        case abi.BytesTy:
            if len(param)>2 {
                if (param[0]=='0') && (param[1]=='x') {
                    param=param[2:]         // cut 0x prefix
                }
            }
            decoded_bytes,tmperr:=hex.DecodeString(param)
            v=decoded_bytes
            err=tmperr
        case abi.BoolTy:
            val:=new(bool)
            v=val
            err=json.Unmarshal([]byte(param),v)
        default:
            err=errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Not supported parameter type: %v",arg.Type))
    }
    return v,err
}
```

Full tutorial on how to pack and upack values for a contract is here:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's over 100 lines of code. I'm looking for something less verbose, ideally single digits in terms of LOC.

Comment: it is 1 line too. the 100 lines is a use case for a C++ app

Comment: OK, possibly more what I was looking for. Can you explain how you got `contract_abi`? That variable seems to appear out of nowhere, and it seems to be the important part.

Comment: `contract_abi` is the object of type `abi.ABI` defined in `./accounts/abi/abi.go` , you get it feeding the abi string , for example: `erc20_methods_abi, err = abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(erc20_methods_abi_json_str))`  (`erc20_methods_abi_json_str` is an ASCII string with the abi definition)

Comment: Could you include that in your answer? The C++ part is misleading because it's not really clear what it really does without reading it, and it's a lot of code.

Comment: @SteveEllis you do not need to learn all of this, the link in the answer points to the tutorial that automatically creates code to call contract's methods in golang. You only need to learn if you want to call the ABI methods directly, like my C++ example.