# How to estimate gas cost for contract method using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, gas-estimate

I want to estimate a contract method gas cost **using geth**. I understand there is no direct way using geth as in the web3 libs. But I don't understand what is the second argument needed and how I can get it.

The second argument is `msg ethereum.CallMsg` from here:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/69c52bde3f5e48a3b74264bf4854e9768ede75b2/ethclient/ethclient.go#L472

How can I get it, **specifically using the Golang implementation**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Ethereum estimate the gas for running a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13328/how-ethereum-estimate-the-gas-for-running-a-contract)

Comment: The linked article is not a duplicate. Firstly, it asks whether it's possible, while I'm asking how. Secondly, the how has also been answered but using web3py and web3js. I'm asking specifically using geth, aka go-ethereum.

Comment: To estimate Gas Limit correctly you have to make a fork of geth and add this functionality I am describing here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/if-metamask-gas-calculations-are-nearly-perfect-why-do-we-still-get-out-of-gas-e/56444#56444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CallMsg` is defined in ./interfaces.go in `geth`s code at root directory:

```
// CallMsg contains parameters for contract calls.
type CallMsg struct {
    From     common.Address  // the sender of the 'transaction'
    To       *common.Address // the destination contract (nil for contract creation)
    Gas      uint64          // if 0, the call executes with near-infinite gas
    GasPrice *big.Int        // wei <-> gas exchange ratio
    Value    *big.Int        // amount of wei sent along with the call
    Data     []byte          // input data, usually an ABI-encoded contract method invocation
}
```

You can get the data with the help of the output of function `transaction.AsMessage()`, defined in `core/types/transaction.go`:

```
func (tx *Transaction) AsMessage(s Signer) (Message, error) {
    msg := Message{
        nonce:      tx.data.AccountNonce,
        gasLimit:   tx.data.GasLimit,
        gasPrice:   new(big.Int).Set(tx.data.Price),
        to:         tx.data.Recipient,
        amount:     tx.data.Amount,
        data:       tx.data.Payload,
        checkNonce: true,
    }

    var err error
    msg.from, err = Sender(s, tx)
    return msg, err
}
```

However you have to have a `types.Transaction` object already made

Of course you can create a struct `CallMsg` yourself and fill the corresponding fields:

```
to:=common.Address{}
msg:=CallMsg {
    From: common.Address{},
    To: &to,
    Gas: 21000,
    GasPrice: big.NewInt(18000000000),
    Value: big.NewInt(666),
    Data: nil,
}
```

Comment: What about the Data part? How do I get an ABI-encoded contract method invocation using geth?

Comment: @sirodoht, check this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56689/ethereumjs-abi-equivalent-for-golang/56783#56783